# Add The Persian language

Tags: locale, mapbox, farsi

I want to use Mapbox with the Persian language. I searched in the MapBox API Documentation And I didn't find anything. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Mapbox Streets v8 reference](https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/mapbox-streets-v8/) details the information provided by the default Mapbox Streets tileset. The languages in which label names are globally available are documented [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/mapbox-streets-v8/#name-text--name_lang-code-text). Additionally, each map label with a `name` field has a [`name_script` field](https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/mapbox-streets-v8/#name_script-text), which indicates the primary language used in that text (this is helpful for styling maps by the "local" language). Unfortunately, Persian is neither provided as a global nor local language at this time, but I would recommend keeping an eye on these references to see if label language availability changes in the future.

If you have the Persian label data yourself, you could [upload the data to Mapbox](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/uploads/) and add it as a layer to a custom map style. Alternatively, if you have a relatively small number of map labels whose language you need to changed, you could follow this guide on [customizing label text for a single label](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/customize-label-text/) to replace the text with its Persian equivalent.